# delete selected rows from table php Angularjs

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

i'm trying to delete multiple rows from table using angularjs and php , 
the problem i'm facing that i'm only able to delete one row each time !

this is my table :

```
<div class="table-responsive" style="overflow-x: unset;">           
    <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deleteBulk()" >Delete</button>
    <table datatable="ng" dt-options="vm.dtOptions" class="table table-bordered table-striped" >
        <thead>
            <tr>                
                <th ><input type="checkbox" ng-model="master" > select</th>
                <th>date</th>
                <th>first name</th>
                <th>last name</th>
                <th>age</th>
                <th>action</th>
                <th>action</th>
                <th>action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr id="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" ng-repeat="name in namesData">
                <td name="checkbox">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="arrExample"
                         ng-model="arrInput" ng-true-value="{{name.id}}"
                         ng-checked="master"
                         ng-click='pushInArray(name.id)'>
                </td>
                <td>{{name.date}}</td>
                <td>{{name.first_name}}</td>
                <td>{{name.last_name}}</td>
                <td>{{name.age}}</td>
                <td><button type="button" ng-click="fetchSingleData(name.id)"
                            class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">edit</button></td>
                <td><button type="button" ng-click="deleteData(name.id)"
                            class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">delete</button></td>
                <td><button type="button" ng-click="single_move(name.id)"
                            class="btn btn-success btn-xs">send</button></td>            
            </tr>
        </tbody>            
    </table>
```

and this is my Angular code :

```
$scope.exampleArray = [];
$scope.pushInArray = function(id) {
     // get the input value
     var inputVal = id;
     var array = $scope.exampleArray.push(inputVal);
     $scope.deleteBulk = function(){
        if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?")){
             $http({
                 method:"POST",
                 url:"insert.php",
                 data:{'id':id, 'action' : 'deleteBulk'}
             }).success(function(data){
                    $scope.success = true;
                    $scope.error = false;
                    $scope.successMessage = data.message;
                    $scope.fetchData();
             });
        }
    };   
};
```

and this is my php code inside insert.php

```
if($form_data->action == "deleteBulk")
{
    $query = "
     DELETE FROM orders WHERE id='".$form_data->id."'
    ";
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    if($statement->execute())
    {
        $output['message'] = 'done!';
    }
}
```

can anyone tell me how to fix it please ?

thank you

Comment: Where are you stating you want to delete multiple rows? Basically there are 2 ways to do it. Either `DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE id IN (1,2,3)` or a `foreach` statement with separate `delete` query for each row.

Comment: how could i make that with foreach statement ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't define a scope function inside another scope function:

> ERRONEOUS
>
> ```
> $scope.exampleArray = [];
> $scope.pushInArray = function(id) {
>      // get the input value
>      var inputVal = id;
>      var array = $scope.exampleArray.push(inputVal);
>      $scope.deleteBulk = function(){
>         if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?")){
>              $http({
>                  method:"POST",
>                  url:"insert.php",
>                  data:{'id':id, 'action' : 'deleteBulk'}
>              }).success(function(data){
>                     $scope.success = true;
>                     $scope.error = false;
>                     $scope.successMessage = data.message;
>                     $scope.fetchData();
>              });
>         }
>     };   
> };
> ```

BETTER

```
$scope.exampleArray = [];
$scope.pushInArray = function(id) {
    // get the input value
    var inputVal = id;
    $scope.exampleArray.push(inputVal);
};

$scope.deleteBulk = function(){
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?")){
         $http({
             method:"POST",
             url:"insert.php",
             data:{'id':id, 'action' : 'deleteBulk'}
         }).then(function(response){
             var data = response.data;   
             $scope.success = true;
             $scope.error = false;
             $scope.successMessage = data.message;
             $scope.fetchData();
         });
    }
};
```

Comment: when i used your code nothing happened when i clicked submit button